# No connectivity at CAT6 Ports

Tags: networking, ethernet, cat6, cat5e

I've been running into a bit of a weird issue, so hopefully this run down will help someone come up with ideas I haven't had.

I'm setting up a new home that has the following:

- CAT5E 350MHz T.568C.2 wiring throughout the house
- 5 rooms connected with CAT6 ports
- 5 Terminators in a patch-panel that are then patch cabled to a switch which is then connected to the router
- All connections are wired with T.568B, white-orange pin 1, and orange in pin 2.

The issue I'm running across is that using a 10BASET connector shows all the pins are set correctly, and the lines are feeding all the transmit channels, yet when we connect any kind of ethernet/internet device (my laptop for example) nothing gets transmitted across the line.

At this point I'm stumped and any help would be greatly appreciated.